# Need help understanding how to find getLength() of the iterable

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I am having trouble understanding how I am mean't to find the getLength() of an iterable in my homework. The class is supposed to be a "toolkit" with useful methods for working on iterables and iterators.

```
   /** Computes the length of an Iterable.
       The length of an Iterable is the total number of entries it returns.
   public static <T> int getLength(Iterable<T> iterable)
   {
      int numEntries = 0;
      while(iterable.hasNext()) {
         numEntries++;
         iterable.next();
      }
      return numEntries;
   }
```

This is what I currently have but I am getting this

```
Toolkit.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      while(iterable.hasNext()) {
                    ^
  symbol:   method hasNext()
  location: variable iterable of type Iterable<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>getLength(Iterable<T>)
```

Comment: You have to call `Iterable.iterator()`

Comment: ^ And store the resulting `Iterator` in a variable so you can use it in your while loop.

Comment: Also, I don't know if the method signature was provided for you, but the type parameter (the `<T>`) is not necessary. The method does not rely on the type of the elements in the iterable, so the method parameter could just be `Iterable<?>`.

Comment: Or `for (T dummy : iterable) numEntries++;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conceptually doesn't work. The concept of an `Iterable` is **solely** that you can ask it to make iterators. It is the iterator that has the whole `hasNext` and `next` thing going on. Iterables are not guaranteed to return the same iterator everytime you ask for an iterator; you may call `iterator()` and see 500 items, and then call it again and see 512. You have no particular guarantees, therefore, 'ask for the length of an iterable' **is not answerable**. For some specific known iterables, such as `ArrayList`, you can answer the question and it'll be easy to do so, but there are iterables for which you cannot do this. Various iterables can only be asked for an `iterator()` once, for example, anything representing a streaming concept (let's say your iterable is a firehose of all telegram messages sent to a telegram channel).

In other words, this is silly homework; whomever gave it does not fully understand what these concepts represent. This code will work for **some** iterables, but will fail for many others, either invalidating the ability to iterate through it after calling this, or crashing, or giving the wrong answer - it's exactly what you wrote, except, make an iterator first. While we're at it, lets get rid of that useless `<T>` here, we don't need it:

```
public static int getLength(Iterable<?> iterable) {
  int numEntries = 0;
  var iterator = iterable.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    numEntries++;
    iterator.next();
  }
  return numEntries;
}
```

However, given that this doesn't actually 'work', I'd write something quite different:

```
public static int getLength(Iterable<?> iterable) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (iterable instanceof Collection<?>) return ((Collection<?>) iterable).size();
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know how to obtain the size for an iterable of type " + iterable.getClass());
}
```

Really, the error in the whole setup is the argument. It should have been `Collection<?>` all along. Almost all iterables you will ever meet implement `Collection` - the main difference between Iterable and Collection is in fact that you can ask a collection how large it is. Iterable exists specifically *because* it represents a type where 'can I know how large you are' is *not* a required ability. Further highlighting how very silly this homework is.

Feel free to direct your teacher to this answer. If it's a general tutorial or book, toss it and get another one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static int size(`Iterable` data) {

    if (data instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection<?>) data).size();
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (Object i : data) {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```